# want to put the focus and edit the first cell of my dynamic table

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to put the focus and edit the first cell of my dynamic table when the user clicks a button.

the problem is that the id of the table tag is dynamic. actually, the name I put in dtoutput is a div tag, which contains neither cell nor row to position with javascrpt.
The problem is that the identification of the html tag of the table is dynamic. Actually, the name that I put in dtoutput is a div tag, and therefore its javascrpt object does not contain a cell or a row to position.

I have tried to position myself in different ways:

```
# tablet_list_var_dtf.cell (': eq (0)'). node (). focus ();
# tablet_list_var_dtf.cell (': eq (1)', ': eq (0)') .focus ();
# tablet_list_var_dtf.cell (': eq (' + scrollStart + ')', ': eq (0)') .focus ();
```

but as I say, really 'tablet_list_var_dtf' is an HTMLDivElement object and therefore it does not have node, cell, row etc ... also I cannot directly use object.focus (), it does not work.

Not only do I want to put the focus, but I want to edit the first cell, force a doubleclick event on said cell ..
I put a summary and executable code of the problem

```
enter code here
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyFeedback)

# JS refocus function
jscode <- " 
  shinyjs.refocus = function(e_id ) {
  alert(e_id);
   alert(eval(tablet_list_var_dtf));
   tablet_list_var_dtf.datatable.row().focus();
 

  
    var scrollStart = tablet_list_var_dtf.scroller.page().start;
    alert('ppp:'+scrollStart);
    
}"
#tablet_list_var_dtf.cell(':eq(0)').node().focus();
#tablet_list_var_dtf.cell( ':eq(1)', ':eq(0)' ).focus();
#tablet_list_var_dtf.cell( ':eq(' + scrollStart + ')', ':eq(0)' ).focus();
#table.cell(':eq(0)').focus()
#shinyjs.refocus = function(e_id) {
#document.getElementById(e_id).focus();
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("refocus") ),
  # activate shiny feedback
  box(wclass = "map", 
      width  = 12,
      style  = 'padding:0px;',
      title  = "List of DTF",
      uiOutput( ("list_var_dtf"))
  ) ,
  actionButton( ('edit_name_var_dtf'),'edit name var description'),
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$edit_name_var_dtf, {
    print("edit_name_var_dtf")
    
    js$refocus("tablet_list_var_dtf")
    print('js$refocus(table)')
  })
  output$list_var_dtf <- renderUI({
    DTOutput(("tablet_list_var_dtf"))
  })
  output$tablet_list_var_dtf  <- renderDT(
    datatable(  data = mtcars,
                rownames  = FALSE,
                options   = list(
                  orderClasses    = TRUE,
                  order           = list(1, "desc"),
                  scrollX         = TRUE,
                  scrollY         = "37vh",
                  searchHighlight = TRUE,
                  scrollCollapse  = T,
                  dom             = 'ft',
                  paging          = FALSE,
                  #callback        = JS(jscall),
                  initComplete    = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                       "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                       "}")
                ),
                selection =  "none" , editable = list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = c(1)))) 
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is the js code correct:
jscode <- "
shinyjs.refocus = function(e_id ) {
var table = $('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable();
var td = table.cell(':eq(0)', ':eq(0)').node();
$(td).attr('tabindex', 0);
$(td).dblclick( );
}"

The problem is search the selector 'DataTables_Table_(XXX)' in a dinamic table into shiny...
one of the problems is the selector. the id 'table_list_var_dtf' is not really the id of the table. the table is dynamically created and starts DataTables_Table_ (xxxxxx) ..
thankssss..

Comment: Instead of posting code in a comment, you can edit your question to include it in a more readable form.

Answer (score 0):

This is the js code correct:

> jscode <- " shinyjs.refocus = function(e_id){
> var table = $('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable();
> var td = table.cell(':eq(0)', ':eq(0)').node();
> $(td).attr('tabindex', 0); $(td).dblclick( );
> }"

The problem is looking for the 'DataTables_Table_(XXX)' selector in a pivot table in shiny. So the real problem is finding the right selector for the table.
If our component id is 'table_list_var_dtf'

> DTOutput('table_list_var_dtf')

you should know that this id is not really the id of the table. But the id of the div that contains the pivot table. Specifically, the table that is created dynamically starts with the name DataTables_Table_ (xxxxxx) . Where (xxxxxx) is the number of tables that have been created dynamically.
Thus, if there are only two tables on the page, the id to look for is: DataTables_Table_ 02

thankssss. jogugil...